# Move to Directory and Run Smashing/Dashing from that Directory

Tags: ruby, raspberry-pi, dashing

I am attempting to automatically start my Smashing Dashboard when my Raspberry Pi boots. I plan to run a script through the @reboot option in crontab (similarily to how I already automatically shutdown the dashboard). However I'm having trouble running the script below.

```
    command  = 'cd "/home/pi/test"' 
    command2 = 'smashing start'


    system "echo hi"
    system command
    puts command
    system "echo Movement"
    system command2
    puts command2

The script itself is just being run from the terminal just now using 

    ruby /home/pi/start_up.rb.
```

Starting Smashing appears to fail because the working directory is not moved through the `cd "home/pi/test"`command as when the script is run I recieve the following error

```
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory
```

There certainly is a Gemfile in the Test directory. This is the same error I get if I run `smashing start` directly from the home/pi folder suggesting that folder is never moved. Is there a correct way to do this?
Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: why don't you `cd` from the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cd "/home/pi/test"` didn't work because `cd` is a shell built-in.  It changed the directory in the shell, but not in Ruby.

To change the directory in Ruby, use

```
Dir.chdir '/home/pi/test'
```

Each process has its own current directory.  Ruby's `Kernel#system` spawned a shell process (probably `/bin/sh`) to run the command, then waited for the shell to exit.  The shell changed directory, then exited.  Ruby never changed directory.